# Remove field errors when resetting a form with a FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

In my Angualar application I have a form with several text fields like order ID and order date.  My form also has a FormArray where each element is a FormGroup representing a row of fields.  This form array has 1 FormGroup at startup and more can be addedby clicking on a button.  After I submit my form  I want to reset the form after getting a succesful response from posting data to a REST service. My reset code form is as follows.:

```
resetItems(): void {
  this.orderForm.reset();
  this.clearErrorsFromFormGroup(this.orderForm);
  let items = this.orderForm.get('items') as FormArray;
  items.controls = [];
  this.addItem();
  this.clearErrorsFromFormGroup(items.at(0) as FormGroup);


}

  private clearErrorsFromFormGroup(formGroup: FormGroup): void {
    Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(key => {
      formGroup.controls[key].setErrors(null);
    });
  }
```

When executing the above the top level fields like order Id and Order date  are reset and are not highlighted red as I have removed the errors.  I want to set my form array to be the same way it was at start up with 1 element.  My code clears the form array and adds a rowData Element. I then clear the errors for the rowData FormGroup.  On the UI The fields for this rowData are all cleared  but theys are highlighted red even though I have cleared the errors.  Can anyone help please?

I have included a StackBlitz link to demonstrate this at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8qjphu

Comment: your stackblitz demo doesn't have the code you have above

Comment: Sorry about that @brijmcq.  I have now. updated the link with the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `items` is a `FormArray` and the way you clear your controls won't work.

Check this code

```
 Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(key => {
      formGroup.controls[key].setErrors(null);
    });
```

Imagine that you hit the `items` key here

```
formGroup.controls['item'] // this is a FormArray and 
// not FormControl so setErrors(null) won't work here
```

One way to fix this is to check for the instance of FormArray then iterate on the controls field and you can use the `clearValidators` and `updateValueAndValidty` functions.

```
   if (formGroup.controls[key] instanceof FormArray) {
         const control = formGroup.get(key) as FormArray;
        for (let i = 0; i < control.controls.length; i++) {
          const formGroup = control.controls[i] as FormGroup;
          Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(field => {
            const control = formGroup.get(field);
            control.clearValidators();
            control.updateValueAndValidity();
          });
        }
      }
```

Here's a stackblitz demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f7pflm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Here's how your `clearErrorsFromFormGroup` woud look like now

```
private clearErrorsFromFormGroup(formGroup: FormGroup): void {
    Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(key => {
      formGroup.controls[key].setErrors(null);
       if (formGroup.controls[key] instanceof FormArray) {
         const control = formGroup.get(key) as FormArray;
        for (let i = 0; i < control.controls.length; i++) {
          const formGroup = control.controls[i] as FormGroup;
          console.log('control', control);
          Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(field => {
            const control = formGroup.get(field);
            control.clearValidators();
            control.updateValueAndValidity();
          });
        }
      }

    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `formGroup.updateValueAndValidity()` method after reset